# Relation between desktop environment, windowing system and GUI libraries

Tags: xorg, gui, desktop-environments, window-manager

I'm trying to understand the relationship between desktop environments (e.g. KDE, Cinnamon, GNOME), windowing systems (X, Wayland) and GUI libraries (Qt, GTK). Here are some things I think I understood (correct me!):

- desktop environments are coded with specific libraries (e.g. Cinnamon based on GTK, LXQt based on Qt) ; they define the particular look and feel of the GUI
- libraries are in charge of drawing the particular widgets (buttons, text fields, etc) that I interact with.
- they do so by sending drawing instructions to the windowing system (e.g. draw a rounded rectangle for my button).

However, something seems off in this picture: running Cinnamon (GTK-based), I can totally code and run programs which use Qt.
How can particular programs use their own GUI library, (and send their own drawing instructions)? Isn't the desktop environments is the one supposed to define the form and shape of shape of windows?

Comment: You can have both Qt & GTK libs in memory (inc. GTK2, GTK3 & Qt5...) at the same time, this won't be a problem if you have loads of memory in your box, but it'll mean lots of paging & a very slow experience if you've limited RAM.  I as a general rule tend to ignore toolkits & libraries used where boxes have >4GB of RAM, take minor interest at 4GB, but take careful notice if box has 2GB, esp. with 1GB.  The more libs/toolkits in use just means more overhead (esp. RAM used)... DEs don't define everything (Lubuntu uses LXQt with Openbox, which handles maximize, minimize etc, as LXQt can't)

Comment: Software is built as a stack, and you can drop in and replace various components (use LXQt on Debian and it'll by default use `xfwm4` from the XFCE team instead of Openbox).  The programmer has control over what they use, and they tend to choose efficient tools that meet their needs or project aims (LXQt; the L means light which is taken seriously). End users though are free to waste ram by choosing GTK programs still, packagers are free to use different WMs (my openbox/xfwm4 example) and build the system as they choose.  Once installed you can replace components too...

Answer (score 1):

**User experience**

You can have both Qt & GTK libs in memory (inc. GTK2, GTK3 & Qt5...) at the same time, this won't be a problem if you have loads of memory in your box, but it'll mean lots of paging & a very slow experience if you've limited RAM.

I as a general rule tend to ignore toolkits & libraries used where boxes have >4GB of RAM, take minor interest at 4GB, but take careful notice if box has 2GB, esp. with 1GB. The more libs/toolkits in use just means more overhead (esp. RAM used)...

**Desktops**  (using LXQt as example)

DEs don't define everything (Lubuntu uses LXQt with Openbox, which handles maximize, minimize etc, as LXQt can't)

Software is built as a stack, and you can drop in and replace various components (use LXQt on Debian and it'll by default use `xfwm4` from the XFCE project instead of Openbox preferred by Lubuntu team).

The programmer has control over what they use, and they tend to choose efficient tools that meet their needs or project aims (*LXQt; the L means light which is taken seriously*).

**Choice**

End users though are free to waste ram by choosing GTK programs still, packagers are free to use different WMs (my openbox/xfwm4 example) and build the system as they choose.

Once installed you can replace components too.

GNU/Linux users have choice, we can pick & choose which parts of the various system exists in our stack, even double up and use multiple libs/toolkits that do the same thing differently & waste resources, just because we can, or it pleases us.

Comment: Not well thought out, just ramblings really... I've voted to close question as too broad, so it'll get closed or changed... hopefully I made my point (*within my distracted rambling*)